# Pairwise comparison algorithm with time complexity better than O(n**2)

Tags: python, performance, comparison, pairwise

I have around 500,000 arrays of 10 words i.e. 500,000 word 10-grams. For every 10-gram, I need to know in which positions, if any, the remaining 499,999 10-grams have identical elements:

*a* = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

*b* = ['A', 'M', 'C', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'G', 'M', 'I', 'M']

...

*z* = ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

If we use a 1 for positions where the two arrays contain the same word and a 0 for positions where they contain different words, the intersection of *a* with *b* would be represented as [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]; the intersection of *a* with *z* would be represented as [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], etc.

Can we do better than a naive O(n**2) algorithm, i.e. one for loop within another for loop?

Comment: It seems that you want to fill a n x n matrix n x n, I do not see how this could be done in less than O(n**2).  May be you should switch to an algorithm that does not require pairwise comparison.

Comment: I tried several (much more efficient) algorithms but none of them came close to the wonderful results I obtain from this pairwise-comparison algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Fun question :)

So I have an idea and I think it is `O(n*log(n) + n)` where `+n` asymptotically irrelevant.

So I would propose something as follows:

```
tuple_len = 10
min_value = 1
max_value = 10
number_of_entries = 100
l = [[j] + [randint(min_value,max_value) for i in range(tuple_len)] for j in range(number_of_entries)]
```

Base set:

```
[[0, 9, 10, 3, 6, 3, 10, 9, 7, 8, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 2, 5, 10, 6, 10],
 [2, 5, 4, 10, 8, 5, 9, 2, 7, 4, 3],
 [3, 5, 9, 4, 5, 5, 3, 10, 1, 4, 4],
 [4, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 6, 1, 6, 2],
 [5, 5, 6, 3, 6, 9, 5, 8, 3, 1, 1],
 [6, 9, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6],
 [7, 2, 6, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5],
 [8, 6, 8, 9, 3, 7, 1, 2, 9, 8, 10],
 [9, 7, 5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 9],
 [10, 1, 4, 4, 3, 6, 9, 6, 3, 3, 8],
 [11, 8, 3, 10, 10, 5, 9, 7, 3, 4, 5],
...]
```

So I just used numbers for convenience and added the position in list as first value.

I propose to sort the dataset for each column of the data in turn, where sorting is `O(n*log(n))`, and then add the positional value of all entries with the same value to a set, which is `O(n)`. The result looks something like:

```
[{6, 18, 24, 26},
 {22, 34},
 {1, 6, 19, 31, 57, 58},
 {1, 9, 18},
...}
```

This can be interpreted as `Entry 6, 18, 24 and 26 have the same value in position 1.`
Checking if two entries correspond is `Ò(1)` with

`true if (a in match_set) and (b in match_set) else false`

Code example below:

```
match_sets = [set() for i in range(tuple_len)]


for position in range(tuple_len):
    l = sorted(l, key= lambda x: x[position+1])
    last_value = l[0][position+1]
    for entry in range(number_of_entries):
        if l[entry][position + 1] == last_value:
            match_sets[position].add(l[entry][0])
            last_value = l[entry][position + 1]
```

Comment: I may be wrong but this does not seems to answer the question. In what time the n x n matrix can be filled from `match_sets `? BTW, see my comment under the question.

Comment: You are right, in that it does not fill the matrix in that time, but filling a nxn matrix can never be faster than ```O(n²)```. However, the list of sets does contain the same information, with similar access complexity, therefore  it may still be of interest